# Need help on xCode Memory Report -> Utilization Comparison

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

In xCode, I am looking at the Memory Report view (not in Instrument). The top right section is named : Utilization Comparison. All is fine for my app's memory consumption (around 20mb) but the "Other Processes" section occupies up to 400mb ! I have no other apps opened...Its almost half of my iPad (1Gb) memory...Someone have a clue on what that "Other Processes" section represents? I don't think the OS would take half of the memory it does not make sense.